# how to fetch data from wordpress database and display into custom web page?

Tags: wordpress, mysqli

I am currently working on custom web project. and i tried to fetch some data from the wordpress database and display into my custom page but i failed(neither successful nor unsuccessful message displayed).
below are the codes

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$stable_name = $wpdb->prefix.'head_set';

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $stable_name");
if(empty($result):
   echo "no results";
else:
   echo "data available";
endif;
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I failed*? Do you get any error? Unexpected result? Nothing happens?

Comment: @barbsan nothing displayed when i preview the page